# Is a 6 inch reinforced slab suitable for a 12,000 lb storage tank?

Tags: concrete

I will be building a 200 Sq. feet garage to be used as a pump house for a new home in the desert north of Phoenix, Az. The soil is natural desert (fist size rock 85%, 15 % DC granite and some sand mixed in, all virgin soil that's extremely hard packed). Can I use a 6"or  8" slab with 3/8 rebar 16" grid and be safe with a round water tank Apx. 6 Ft. Round 12,000 Lb. when full?

And what test would it need to be? There will be no plumbing under the slab or in the slab, just sitting on the level virgin desert rock. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: The tank's manufacturer may offer sample plans or other guidance. Try calling them.

Comment: Hi isherwood,  I never thought of that. I think I'm spending way to much time over thinking this, I will cakk several tank manufacture's and I would be willing one of them will have that Info. thank you  Dave F

Answer (score 1):

Geometry time. 6 foot diameter is 3 foot radius is 9π square feet.

Ground loading for 12,000 lbs spread over that area is 425 lbs per square foot (rounded up.) That's not a concern on almost any soil, nor any grade of concrete - it's a very low loading. 1000 lbs per square foot is typically assumed to be fine for even poor (loading-wise) soils.

Answer (score 0):

Probably. Some civil engineering standard should give a good number. Meanwhile , my  home driveway is 4 to 6 in. thick with 1/2 rebar on 24 centers as I remember. I recently had a 10 wheel dump truck with about 7 yards of damp sand clay mix , I guess close to 18,000 lbs , drive across and dump two loads. So the weight of truck and load on the rear wheels were well above your load, and dynamic. My driveway didn't crack . However the concrete is 20 years old so very well cured.

Comment: Thank's for the input Blacksmith37, that's a strong driveway.

Comment: Hi, isherwood I called the tank supplier and they said a sand bed or 6" slab with 1/2 " bar every 18" was overkill. thank you guys Just getting to old to think anymore. Now I can start the fun part. happy 4th.

Comment: Why do it twice when you can do it once. I think Ill go with 6" of concrete.

Comment: Static loads can cause subsidence/settling more than dynamic ones - look at the wheel dents in some carparks.